# The infinity Wasserstein distance $W_\infty$ and the weak topology

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. The $\infty$-Wasserstein distance $W_\infty$ on the space $P(X)$ of Borel probability measures on $X$ can be described as $$W_\infty(\mu,\nu) = \inf\{r>0 \mid \mu(U)\le\nu(U_r)\,\forall \text{ open } U\subseteq X\},$$ where $U_r=\{x\in X \mid d(x,U)\le r\}$. The topology induced by this distance is in general finer than the weak (or vague) topology. For example, if $X=[0,1]$ and $\delta_x$ denotes the point mass at $x$, the measures $\mu_n=\frac{n-1}{n}\delta_0+\frac{1}{n}\delta_1$ converge weakly to $\delta_0$, but $W_\infty(\mu_n,\delta_0)=1$ for every $n$. On the other hand, $W_\infty$ dominates the Levy-Prokhorov distance, so $W_\infty$-convergence does imply weak convergence.

**Question**: is $W_\infty$-convergence equivalent to weak convergence if one restricts to *fully supported* measures?

(Edit: by *fully supported* I mean those measures $\mu$ such that $\mu(U)>0$ for every nonempty open set $U\subseteq X$.)

I believe this is the case at least for $X=[0,1]$, but I just want to make sure it is not obviously ridiculous!

Comment: Could you share your definition of a fully supported measure.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the definition of fully supported.

Comment: For anyone interested, I asked this question on MathOverflow and got a very nice answer (assuming some reasonable connectedness):  https://mathoverflow.net/a/404689/384059.